# Python - modify a global variable

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm using python for create an application. I have two different classes and I'm playing with a global variable. What I want to do is something like this

```
globvar = 0

class one:
  global globvar
  def __init__()
    ...
  def func1()
    ...
    globvar = 1

class two:
  global globvar
  def __init__()
    ...
  def func2()
    ...
    print globvar  # I want to print 1 if I use func1
```

I've done something similar but func2 never print 1, but only 0. So the question is... it's possible change a global variable through different classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your global declaration is at the wrong place; it needs to be at the point you assign to the variable, ie inside `func1`.

That said, there is a much better way of addressing this, without using global at all: make `globvar` a class attribute on a base class that one and two both inherit from.

```
class Base(object):
    globvar = 0

class One(Base):
    def func1(self):
        self.__class__.globvar = 1

class Two(Base):
    def func2(self):
        print self.globvar
```

(Note in `func1` you need to assign via `self.__class`, but in `func2` you can access it directly on `self`, as Python will fall back to the class scope if it doesn't find it on the instance.)

Comment: @Daniel....I was going to add another answer stating that `globals()` as well returns a `dict` containing all global variable and that any of them could be changed as `global()['globvar']=1` ... I just thought it's not recommended...what's your opinion on that?